# Organisation-wide email addresses in Google Apps

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I'm just setting up Google Apps for my non-profit domain. I'd like to be able to have addresses such as `info@mydomain.com` and `admin@mydomain.com` forwarded to certain Apps users. I can do this using the groups facility and have done so.

However, how can I allow each of these users to send email from these addresses?

As far as I can tell each email alias can only be associated with one user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each user can add the group address to the list of accounts that they can send mail from. These steps will need to be repeated for each user.

1. In Mail **Settings** > **Accounts**, click **Add another email address you own**
2. Enter the group email address, and change the name to something appropriate for the group email address.
3. Send the verification email (it will be sent to everyone in the group).
4. Enter the verification code from the email that was sent.
5. When that user composes a new message, he can select the group email from the **From:** drop down list.